# Brighten Minecraft more than the brightest setting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On my crappy laptop screen, even the brightest setting isn't bright enough. Whenever I play on PC, I see a bit into the darkness, but today on Laptop I got surprised by a skeleton, while I had torches and everything.

So is there a way to increase the brightness above the highest brightness setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way!

If you edit your options.txt file located under the %appdata% .minecraft folder. Where it says gamma: 1.0

change this value to 2.0 or higher!

Or just use night vision potions in game, which are meant for that reason!

Comment: I use 3.0 all the time, it's a good brightness, but also doesn't make the weird colours too bad that you get on light levels 6-9 usually.